# ¿Es válido un cross-post entre el sitio en español y el sitio en inglés?

Tags: discusión, moderación

Acabo de darme cuenta por [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/es-stdfunction-es-similar-a-lo-siguiente) y [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533474/this-stdfunction-is-similar-to) ejemplo (ambos post de nuestro amigo y pionero @AngelAngel), que esta situación podría darse con bastante frecuencia.

Pienso que hay casos y casos; abajo planteo 2 historias de usuario diferentes que -creo- vale la pena analizar:

#### Historia de Usuario 1:

Mientras trabajo Hago un "descubrimiento" que, en mi opinión, merece ser compartido y me digo: "Voy a entrara StackOverflow; voy a hacer una pregunta y contestare yo mismo la respuesta **para compartir este conocimiento**", entonces verifico que no sea un duplicado y cuando todo esta listo, *publico mi pregunta-respuesta en el sitio en español, en inglés y en portugués*, el chino lo dejo afuera por que no puedo.

#### Historia de Usuario 2:

Mientras trabajo tengo un problema, investigo, no encuentro una solución, no encuentro una alternativa, no 3, no N... en fin: **me bloqueo**. Y me digo: "Voy a entrar a StackOverflow; voy a buscar la ayuda de esta asombrosa gente" entonces me tomo una hora para reducir el código a su mínima expresión de forma tal que no haya nada no esencial para reproducir el problema *y agrego 3 preguntas en los mismos tres sitios que usuario 1*.

Ahora bien,

**Usuario 2** se ha tomado el trabajo apropiado pero hizo algo que [no estaría permitido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

**Usuario 1** en cambio hizo algo que queremos, ha compartido su conocimiento y lo ha hecho en tres idiomas, pero (a las duras de la ley actual - AFAIK) también hizo algo que no estaría permitido.

Mi pregunta principal: Que consideraciones debería tener/acciones realizar yo como otro usuario (que también modera la comunidad) con una publicación cruzada como esta? (bandera explicativa a un moderador, comentarios, cerrar pregunta, etc)

Ademas, Debería StackExchange flexibilizar el caso de Usuario 1? (Es algo que me parece va de la mano (o cerca) con [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow)).

Gracias!

Comment: Japonés, no chino. :-)

Comment: Esta es una pregunta interesante. Creo que ambas debieran ser permitidas. Si no, la del usuario 1 debe serlo, y el usuario 2 debiera publicar su pregunta en el sitio que considere más apropiado para obtener una respuesta, y luego de esto, publicar su pregunta y la respuesta en los otros idiomas que conoce.

Comment: @Jorge por curiosidad: ¿qué sentido tienen estas ediciones de apenas una de las mil cosas que podrían corregirse de una publicación que, además, no está relacionada con ningún evento actual que justifique relanzarla?

Comment: @fedorqui perdón acabo de ver tu mensaje en el chat, en META realizo cambios de algunas palabras u ortografía , en este caso ví que estaba mal escrita la palabra "descubirmiento", pero como mencionas al editarla se va a los primeros resultados, veo que es de hace mucho tiempo, voy a evitar esto en META,saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jorgesys por tu respuesta y por tomar en consideración mi comentario. Estas ediciones son buenas porque mejoran la publicación, pero ya que estamos siempre es bueno mejorar tanto como sea posible. Un saludo!

Answer (score 5):

El FAQ enlazado hace referencia a sitios distintos (Stack Overflow y Server Fault), mientras que en este caso estamos hablando del mismo sitio en distintos idiomas. Es un caso similar pero no idéntico.

Dado que los sitios SO localizados existen específicamente para servir de ayuda a la gente que no puede comunicarse eficientemente en inglés, yo creo que **si se mantiene la calidad de preguntas y respuestas** no hay ningún problema en realizar publicaciones cruzadas.

Comment: no no... es un caso identico, es un cross-post son dos preguntas hechas ayer, por la misma persona, con 2 horas de diferencia. Ademas no reposnde la pregunta..

Comment: Me refiero al enlace "no estaría permitido", en el cual se trata de una pregunta duplicada en SO y en Server Fault. No es el mismo caso discutido aquí.

Comment: Si pero la respuesta sigue siendo valida

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con que si la calidad es buena se pueda realizar en varios idiomas, para la comunidad creo que sería muy positivo el poder extender su ámbito de actuación e interacción.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

En mi opinión, sí es válido realizar una publicación cruzada entres SO y SOes siempre y cuando se haga bien.

## Explicación

Considero que no hay problema en realizar publicaciones cruzadas entre Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow en español así como en otros sitios de Stack Exchange siempre y cuando:

1. Las distintas publicaciones se realicen con calidad tanto de forma y como de fondo.
2. Mencionar que se trata de publicaciones cruzadas indicando los lugares donde se ha realizado.

## Observaciones

En el sentido estricto no considero conveniente realizar publicaciones cruzadas de preguntas ni de respuestas, sino publicaciones de adaptaciones o derivaciones.

Stack Overflow en español está en fase beta pública, sus propias normas, etiquetas y alcance están en proceso ajuste por la propia comunidad que está proceso de consolidación siendo que Stack Overflow tiene una situación muy diferente, por lo que es muy probable que una traducción directa podría no funcionar pero más importante aún, podría ser muy complicado mantener sincronizadas las distintas publicaciones, en particular, debido a la posibilidad de que se vean afectadas por editores que participan en un sitio pero no en el otro.

Answer (score 0):

Una pregunta en SO no es una publicación arbitrada, es una pregunta al aire. Se debe evitar congestionar el sito con información redundante, pero si una pregunta se publica en varios sitios no es tema tampoco para la policía de preguntas. Apenas tengo un día de entrar al Stackoverflow en español y me encuentro un ambiente ríspido que no va ayudar a que la pagina crezca en impacto e importancia. Afortunadamente se ve que muchos participan de manera positiva sin entrar en el juego de poder  y dan respuestas increíblemente detalladas.

Comment: Hola Rubén ¿cómo estás?

Comment: Platiquemos en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)

Comment: Ahora estoy ocupado pero en otra ocasión